# Using 'date' in bash shell to add 5 minutes to a defined time with high precision

Tags: linux, date

I’m trying to keep the high (millisecond) precision of my time, shown in my `$TIME` variable.

I’m confused by the output I get, because I try to add 5 minutes, but it looks like it's subtracting 8 hours and 59 minutes?

```
TIME="23:01:05.001"
echo $TIME
date -d "$TIME + 5 min" +"%H:%M:%S.%3N"

23:01:05.001
14:02:05.001
```

But my desired output is:

```
23:06:05.001
```

How can I use `date` with my `$TIME` variable and just add five minutes to it?

Comment: What time zone are you in? This is probably what you are seeing: https://serverfault.com/q/952279/105107

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot more sense now!  Thank you for the follow up.

Answer (score 5):

Seemingly in conflict with other use I've been able to find of `date -d`
It turns out the way to add minutes that works for me is:

```
TIME="23:01:05.001"
echo $TIME
date -d "$TIME 5min" +"%H:%M:%S.%3N"

23:01:05.001
23:06:05.001
```

Comment: Great self-answered question!